# Comparing count of an NSArray with an integer value leads to incorrect code execution

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am facing a peculiar issue in an iPhone program. This is my code -

In the viewDidLoad of my view controller I create an array

```
grades = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Grade 1", @"Grade 2", @"Grade 3", nil] retain];
```

Now I have a property

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedGradeIndex;
```

And I wrote the following setter method

```
- (void) setSelectedGradeIndex:(NSInteger)newValue
{
  if(newValue >= [grades count])
  {
    NSLog(@"newValue = %d >= [grades count] = %d",newValue, [grades count]);
    newValue = 0;
  }
  else if(newValue < 0)
  {
    NSLog(@"newValue = %d < 0",newValue);
    newValue = [grades count] - 1;
  }

  selectedGradeIndex = newValue;
  lblGrade.text=  [grades objectAtIndex:selectedGradeIndex];
}
```

Somewhere in the code I have

```
self.selectedGradeIndex = -1;
```

The log inside the setter shows

```
newValue = -1 >= [grades count] = 6
```

I am confused. Why will the control go inside the first if condition when the log clearly shows that the condition is false.

I changed the setter to

```
- (void) setSelectedGradeIndex:(NSInteger)newValue
{
  int count = [grades count];
  if(newValue >= count)
  {
    NSLog(@"newValue = %d >= count = %d",newValue, count);
    newValue = 0;
  }
  else if(newValue < 0)
  {
    NSLog(@"newValue = %d < 0",newValue);
    newValue = count - 1;
  }

  selectedGradeIndex = newValue;
  lblGrade.text=  [grades objectAtIndex:selectedGradeIndex];
}
```

And now everything works as expected. The log is

```
newValue = -1 < 0
```

Can some tell me why is the earlier method failing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compare a signed int (your variable) with an unsigned int (the type of `-[NSArray count]`, the signed int is promoted to an unsigned. The number `-1` translates to an extremely large unsigned int. Thus, `-1 > 6`.